# How to call a PreferenceFragment from a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, preferences

I have a class profileFragment that extends PreferenceFragment. I have another class myFragment which extends fragment. How can I call a PreferenceFragment class within a Fragment class? Its important because I use a sliding menu that is based on fragments, thus I cannot call the PreferenceFragment from anywhere else besides within Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to give you a full answer, as it seems to me if you have a sliding menu based on fragments, you could just add a "Settings" option in your sliding menu, and navigate to it using the FragmentManager from the Activity.

A few things you may want to consider (I'd personally recommend looking at #3):

1. As I mentioned above, having a separate "Settings" Navigation item in your sliding menu.
2. Making a call from your normal fragment to your Activity to navigate to the PreferenceFragment. You'd want to read up on [Fragment Communication](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)to learn how you should talk to your Activity though.
3. You might not even need a PreferenceFragment. It sounds like maybe a better use case for what you are trying to do might be a [DialogPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html).
4. You could also look into using Child Fragments ( getChildFragmentManager() ), and having your PreferenceFragment be a child fragment of your other fragment. This is getting a bit complicated though.